# Delete file in Laravel using Google Drive API

Tags: laravel, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm using this command to upload the file to Google Drive (store function in controller):

```
$request->anexo->storeAs('1tD*******************-6', $file_name, 'google');
```

And this to get the link:

```
$link = Storage::disk('google')->url('1tD*******************-6/' . $file_name);
```

This is working fine. But when i try to delete the file i can't find it in the destroy function in the same controller. I've tried the commands below and all of them return false:

```
$att = OrdemAttachment::findOrFail($id);
$link = Storage::disk('google')->url('1tD*******************-6/' . $att->file_name);
// dd($link);
$exists = Storage::disk('google')->has('1tD*******************-6/' . $att->file_name);
// dd($exists);
$delete = Storage::disk('google')->delete('1tD*******************-6/' . $att->file_name);
// dd($delete);
```

Is there another command that must be used instead of these?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was trying to use the file name and even tried to use the google drive link. But what worked was using the file id (you can find the id inside the link). So, for example, if the link to the file is `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1AgF87s1lw9TSsRhVOpGNJ2K6wq3A8FzD&export=media`, to delete the file in google drive with the id would go like this:

```
$delete = Storage::disk('google')->delete('1tD*******************-6/1AgF87s1lw9TSsRhVOpGNJ2K6wq3A8FzD');
```

1tD*******************-6 is the subfolder id and 1AgF87s1lw9TSsRhVOpGNJ2K6wq3A8FzD is the id of the file extracted from the link.